# Specify data type of each columns while training using AWS Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using AWS Sagemaker and train using sagemaker api, Estimators (https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/estimators.html)
However when invoking endpoint, it seems to be not working.

Error message is like this.

```
 An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (415) from model with message "Loading csv data failed with Exception, please ensure data is in csv format:
 <class 'ValueError'>
 could not convert string to float: <String Value>".
```

I assume that when training, feature where the datatype is string seems to be learning in float.
So I think the best solution is to specify data type for each features.
I used XGBoost algorithm.

Is it possible?